# Xamarin Forms: How to Change the textcolor of Collectionview SelectedItem?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uicollectionview, carousel

I have a `CarouselPage` having 5 children and every child has a horizontal collection view. When selecting an item in Collectionview or swiping the pages, I need to give a different text color and need to add an underline for the selected item. I have tried like below:

**CarouselHomePage.cs**

```
public partial class CarouselHomePage : CarouselPage
{
    public List<Activity> activityList { get; set; }
    public CarouselHomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        activityList = new List<Activity>();
        AddActivities();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "child", (s, child) =>
        {
            CurrentPage = Children[Int32.Parse(child)];
        });
    }

    private void AddActivities()
    {
        activityList.Add(new Activity() { Title = "PageNumber1" });
        activityList.Add(new Activity() { Title = "PageNumber2" });
        activityList.Add(new Activity() { Title = "PageNumber3" });
        activityList.Add(new Activity() { Title = "PageNumber4" });
        activityList.Add(new Activity() { Title = "PageNumber5" });
        AddChild(activityList);
    }

    public void AddChild(List<Activity> activityList)
    {
        this.Children.Add(new PageNumber1(activityList));
        this.Children.Add(new PageNumber2(activityList));
        this.Children.Add(new PageNumber3(activityList));
        this.Children.Add(new PageNumber4(activityList));
        this.Children.Add(new PageNumber5(activityList));
    }
}
```

**Activity.cs**

```
public class Activity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool visibility { get; set; }
    public bool Visibility
    {
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                visibility = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return visibility;
        }
    }

    private Color textColor;
    public Color TextColor
    {
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                textColor = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return textColor;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**PageNumber1.xaml**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <CollectionView 
            SelectionMode="Single"
            x:Name="ActivityList"
            Margin="5,10,5,10"
            SelectionChanged="TagItemTapped"
            ItemsLayout="HorizontalList">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout 
                        Orientation="Vertical"
                        Margin="15">

                        <Label
                            TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{Binding Title}">
                            <Label.FontSize>
                                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                    <OnIdiom.Phone>18</OnIdiom.Phone>
                                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>27</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                                    <OnIdiom.Desktop>18</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                                </OnIdiom>
                            </Label.FontSize>
                        </Label>

                        <BoxView 
                            HeightRequest="2"
                            IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"
                            BackgroundColor="{Binding TextColor}" 
                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <CollectionView.HeightRequest>
                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                    <OnIdiom.Phone>30</OnIdiom.Phone>
                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>60</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                    <OnIdiom.Desktop>30</OnIdiom.Desktop>
                </OnIdiom>
            </CollectionView.HeightRequest>
        </CollectionView>

        <Label Text="Welcome to PageNumber1"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**PageNumber1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class PageNumber1 : ContentPage
{
    public PageNumber1(List<Activity> activityList)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (activityList == null)
        {
            ActivityList.IsVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < activityList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (activityList[i].Title == "PageNumber1")
                {
                    activityList[i].TextColor = Color.FromHex("#26b4d8");
                    activityList[i].Visibility = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    activityList[i].TextColor = Color.Gray;
                    activityList[i].Visibility = false;
                }
            }
            ActivityList.ItemsSource = activityList;
        }
    }
    public void TagItemTapped(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedItem = (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Activity);
        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            string childnumber = "";
            if (selectedItem.Title == "PageNumber1")
            {
                childnumber = "0";
            }
            else if (selectedItem.Title == "PageNumber2")
            {
                childnumber = "1";
            }
            else if (selectedItem.Title == "PageNumber3")
            {
                childnumber = "2";
            }
            else if (selectedItem.Title == "PageNumber4")
            {
                childnumber = "3";
            }
            else if (selectedItem.Title == "PageNumber5")
            {
                childnumber = "4";
            }
            MessagingCenter.Send<App, string>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "child", childnumber);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added the same code on all the other child pages with the corresponding title in the if statement. But the selected page title color is not working and underline is not showing.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Also if I select the last item in the collectionview, I need to scroll the collection on the last child to the last item. For this I have used `ScrollTo` feature of Collectioview. But that is also not working.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    ActivityList.ScrollTo(4);
}
```

The above code will work if I manually swipe the pages. When directly tap the collectionview item, the scrolling is not working.

I have uploaded a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZznFgTul-dU4WPELdnn4U-NvlPLlILgN).

Comment: Thanks for sharing sample , I will check that .

Comment: I found the `CollectionView` created multiple times ，that should be the reason why not shows correctly .Here suggest that not adding `CollectionView` into every child page .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I have uploaded a sample video [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11B4OOyTJj0QzNpVsNzM2pir2Dst-YPsv).

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT This is my actual project screens, in every page I am showing data, so every page have collectionview, please go through the video.

Comment: Got it . Then you need a `CarouselPage` .If want to achieve that video's effect , you need to make the `CarouselPage` contain a `CollectionView` and `CarouselView` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212328/discussion-between-sreejith-sree-and-junior-jiang-msft).

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Actually I need to call a service first, after the service I decided what are all the child. In the current sample, I have not added this logic. I have updated the sample with this logic. Could you please have a look? Sorry for the inconvenience  :) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qnP86KPIXcTkBOpNMA8kFyYPHNsHVKmK

Comment: Okey, that means you need to dynamically add View inside it after App launched . I will check that .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes, I am adding child dynamically, thanks.

Comment: I have known why underline not showing and Tapped problems , I will update an answer that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About *underline not showing* , the reason is `HeightRequest` of **CollectionView** setted too small with `30` .

Modify that to above `35` , it will show correcttly . Such as :

```
<CollectionView.HeightRequest>
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
        <OnIdiom.Phone>40</OnIdiom.Phone>
        <OnIdiom.Tablet>60</OnIdiom.Tablet>
        <OnIdiom.Desktop>30</OnIdiom.Desktop>
    </OnIdiom>
</CollectionView.HeightRequest>
```

The effect :

[image]

About selected problem , this is [the sample project here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bcqhmnyko0jkya0/AppCarouselWithCollection.rar?dl=0) .

[image]