# How to show the tabbed icons with scrollable instead of more(3 dots) in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I implemented the Tabbed page with 9 tab.I'm displaying the 9 icons. It displaying 4 icons and 3 dots for remaining icons. How can I show the tabbed icons with scrollable instead of more(3 dots).

Also, I used the below code in **Tabbar.xml**. still, It's not working.

app:tabMode="scrollable"
app:showAsAction="always"

[image]

Please Help me.

Comment: Hi , tabbedpage not suggest too much tabs all show in tab bar . If you need to scroll to show more tabs , you can have a try with `CollectionView` and `CarouselView` to achieve that .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61379921/xamarin-forms-how-to-change-the-textcolor-of-collectionview-selecteditem/61402793#61402793

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT   

Tab bar with scrollable is working fine if tab bar at the top. The more option is displaying whenever I put the tab bar at the bottom

Comment: Okey , that's fact . I will check whether has a solution to make it works at the bottom .

Comment: Its because of this https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/7a52542d50797ccc69ae1d8dd84259190d96bdb4/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/TabbedPageRenderer.cs#L665 , you should create custom renderer if you dont want it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the top navigation for Xamarin Forms but it's not supported out of the box for bottom navigation.

According to [Google's Material Design specification](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/), BottomNavigationView does not support more than 5 items:

> ```
> Note: BottomNavigationView does not support more than 5 menu items.
> ```

More importantly, having more than 5 items in BottomNavigation is bad design in terms of UX. If you need more than 5 items, try to use [Navigation View](https://material.io/develop/android/components/navigation-view/) instead. However, you can create your own BottomNavigationView system, as suggested in the comments above, using a horizontal CollectionView.